# Can a 13 year old wheelie/bunny hop on a mountain bike?

Tags: mountain-bike

I have a regular sized Kona mountain bike and I've been trying to at least *lift* the front properly, for several months. Is it maybe that I weight 105 (only)? What techniques would you recommend for somebody like me? I know bunny hops are usually for BMX, but they're useful for MTB a whole lot, for example [this channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-OkWl_1M4s) gives tips on starting, but for adult sized bodies I would suppose. Thank you.

Comment: Cleats make bunny hopping dead-simple.  Try locking out any suspension too - it could be soaking up your jump's momentum.

Comment: A bike that is too large will make it really hard to master, to the point of frustration. If you get a chance, borrowed a mates BMX or smaller MTB and see how you go.

Comment: Your weight probably has a lot to do with it, but keep it up and you'll be doing wheelies and bunny hops in no time!

Comment: @Criggie cleats are used for an english bunny hop, but a correctly performed american bunny hop is more effective, and all about momentum and weight distribution

Comment: @AndyP +1 - Don't use cleats to bunnyhop.

Answer (score 6):

Wheelies are about legs and technique so if you can reach the pedals and handlebars you can pull a wheelie on a mountain bike.

But bunny hops need weight so that will be an issue for you since it's a matter of using your weight to get the bounce and momentum you need.

Learning to wheelie (lift the front wheel) is fairly simple you get the bike barely rolling, put it in highest gear, and then push down hard on the pedal while pulling up on the handlebars. Keeping it going is a bit more difficult. I taught my 8 year old to wheelie using that technique but on a smaller bike. Be prepared to spin the whole bike upside down a few times when learning. But doing it this way you can't really get hurt since you're not going at any speed.

Safety first! Don't take the picture too seriously, but practising on grass is a good idea for beginners.

[image]